# onItemClick opening a URL from RSS feed

Tags: android, rss

I have an RSS feed parsed into a list view in my app.  I'm trying to make it pull the link for each item in the rss and open it when I click the item in the listview.  basicly i have everything already in place but not sure what coding i should use after this statement.

public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {

I know that this is where my code should be for opening the url that is saved in the rss file but not sure how to retrieve it from here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

```
//RSS Feed URL
private final String CGR_FEED_URL = "http://www.mychurchevents.com/Calendar/RSS.ashx?days=7&ci=G1M7G1N8K5G1N8N8H2&igd=";

//XML Widgets
private ListView listview_episodes;
private ProgressBar progress_bar;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //XML Widgets by ID
    listview_episodes = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_episodes);
    listview_episodes.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    progress_bar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
    //Make Progress Bar Invisible
    progress_bar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);

    new ArrayList<String>();
    new ArrayList<String>();


    downloadEpisodes(CGR_FEED_URL);

}

private void downloadEpisodes(String Url) {
    //Make Progress Bar Visible While Downloading Feed
    progress_bar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
    Log.d("CGRParser", "Downloading Feed");
    //Start an ASync Thread to take care of Downloading Feed
    new DownloadEpisodes().execute(Url);
}

private class DownloadEpisodes extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, ArrayList<Episode>> {

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Episode> doInBackground(String... url) {

        //Download and Parse Feed
        XmlFeedParser parser = new XmlFeedParser();
        ArrayList<Episode> episodes = new ArrayList<Episode>();
        episodes = parser.parse(url[0]);

        return episodes;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Episode> result) {

        //Feed has been Downloaded and Parsed, Display Data to User
        Log.d("CGRParser", "Feed Download Complete");
        displayEpisodes(result);

    }

}

private void displayEpisodes(ArrayList<Episode> episodes) {

    //Create String Arrays to seperate titles and dates
    Log.d("CGRParser", "Displaying Episode Titles To User");
    ArrayList<String> episode_titles = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> episode_dates = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Episode episode : episodes) {
        Log.d("CGRParser", "Episode Title: " + episode.getTitle());
        episode_titles.add(episode.getTitle());
        episode_dates.add(episode.getDate());
    }

    //Create a ListAdapter to Display the Titles in the ListView
    ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.episode_row, R.id.title, episode_titles);
    listview_episodes.setAdapter(adapter);

    //Set Progress Bar Invisible since we are done with it
    progress_bar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);

}

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {




}
```

}
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just insist to go through [`this`](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/) `Tutorial` and download the complete source and get it working. This will clear up your queries that how it works and also it has included using several `XML` `Parser`*(SAX, DOM, XmlPullParser, some others)* that you will get to learn.

**UPDATE:**

You can use `getSelectedItemPosition()` and get the selected value from the `ListView`. And then do the further process of showing the RSS.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                                                      long id) {
            // get the selected item and do the further process
            listview.getItemAtPosition(position); 
}
```

Comment: I have done that one and never did get it to work the way i needed it to.  I have the xml parsing just fine and everything is working from using another tutorial and modifying it with the stuff i needed.  all i need is to figure out how to make the link load in maybe a webview after i click the item in the list view, but it needs to load the link from the rss file

Comment: Well, then you should post your code to get an exact idea about what you had done and where you are facing problem.

Comment: what all code do you want me to post and i will gladly post it

Comment: Where you are facing problem, that part.

Comment: ok i edited and posted main activity where i'm trying to finish.  the code in question should be at the very bottom